# How can I input shellcode via stdin that will be read as shellcode instead of a string literal from stdin?

Tags: c, unix, fgets, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I am doing a (legal) binary exploitation practice and there is a vulnerable buffer to which I am trying to write a specific memory address. However the user input is collected via fgets from stdin an when I enter my input it does not get parsed as bytes, instead it is parsed as a string literal.

This is what I am trying to pass in:
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\x20\x3d\x00\x00\x01

tried that original way, and AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA$'\x20\x3d\x00\x00\x01', nothing is seeming to work

Comment: If you want to pass particular data on stdin, you just need to write that data to stdin.  Perhaps `print 'AAAAA\x20\x3d' | ./cmd`, but some `printf` implementations don't take \x. (If that is the case, you can use octal.)

Comment: Bash _does_ support `$''`, but it uses C strings; because they're NUL-terminated, by definition you can't include a NUL byte in a C string so `$'\x00'` is just an empty string, not a one-byte string with a NUL. As William shows you above, printf can write a NUL to _output_ given `'\x00'` in the format-string argument position -- note that's _not_ a literal NUL byte as `$'\x00'` purports to create, but rather an escape sequence.

Comment: However, for this to be answerable, we need _actual code you're running_, not just data you're trying to represent, and a means to definitively determine whether your code is doing what you want. (Consider both intended and actual `hexdump -C` or `xxd` outputs as a way to demonstrate that -- though once you have an xxd output with your intended data you could just use `xxd -r` and not mess with printf at all).

Answer (score 0):

When reading from stdin, you will get exactly the bytes provided to stdin. (In binary mode, at least. In text mode, you might get some 0D 0A ⇒ 0A translations in Windows.)

It sounds like you want to provide the following bytes (represented in hex):

```
41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 20 3D 00 00 01
```

To provide those bytes, you could use any of the following:

```bash
perl -e'print pack "H*", "41414141414141414141414141414141203D000001"'

perl -e'print "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA =\x00\x00\x01"'

printf 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA =\x00\x00\x01'
```

(Someone commented that not all `printf` support hex escapes.)

You can verify that the correct bytes are output using `od -t x1`.

```
$ printf 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA =\x00\x00\x01' | od -t x1
0000000 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41
0000020 20 3d 00 00 01
0000025
```